# why is git push rejected even if the file/folder permission is ok?

Tags: git, push, permission-denied

I've set up a remote repo using rsa private/public keys using putty/plink.

I manage to fetch from the remote repo, but I cannot push anything to it.

This is the output I get:

```
C:\cygwin\home\git\new_trunk>git push main login-2
Counting objects: 9993, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6971/6971), done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file: Permission denied
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@remote.ps/appdata/git/yao/webapps.git'
```

The system admin checked that the file permission is good, yet I can't push? Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to write to the temp directory. Try `echo %TMPDIR%`.

Comment: @larsmans what exactly should i see? this tmpdir is it for the repo or for my own computer? i messaged my sys-admin and he sayd the permissions are good..

Comment: This is one of the environment variables that determine where temporary files are stored; it's not Git-specific. If it's set, you should see a path to a directory where you have write permissions.

Comment: @yaojiang This is a permission problem on the remote machine. The repository user needs recursive read and write permissions. Ask your admin to check twice... ;)

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 3 otc git 4096 May 16 13:43 yao, this is what i get

Comment: @madflow checked three times already :(

Comment: check file permissions for every file in the repository, make sure user git has write permissions. I suggest chown'ing them to git:git

Comment: @yao jiang Where did you check the permissions? It has to be the repository dir...

Comment: @madflow the permission was the same as all the other users, yet they can push/fetch with no problems, my team leader stepped in and somehow fixed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to doublecheck the permissions on the folders.